# Dynamically add and remove Angular 5 Material attribute 'multiple'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am probably missing something basic here but am using mat-button-toggle-group and want to be able to use it as a radio button or as checkboxes depending upon application state ie radio button:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group>
```

and checkbox:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group multiple>
```

Normally, I would add and remove a tag's attributes something like this:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [attr.multiple]="test ? multiple:null">
```

..but this doesn't appear to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an attribute. It's an Angular directive in the **mat-button-toggle-group** component. So it's not possible to add multiple dynamically with **[attr.multiple]**

You have to use two mat groups with *ngIf like this :

```
<mat-button-toggle-group *ngIf="test" multiple></mat-button-toggle-group>
<mat-button-toggle-group *ngIf="!test"></mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `multiple` is not an attribute but a directive u can't add it dinamicly without accesing source code of underliyng component (and still it will be just a hack). This is sad news..

But anyways you can create 2 mat groups and rather display or not 1 of them depending on your `test` variable. And save it state, if it needed local varable.

Answer (score 1):

The `multiple` is a native boolean attribute for `<select>`. So only if you use a native select you're able to do the following:

`<select [multiple]="!!yourExpression">`

**Here you are a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsnif8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

---

Unfortunately, I've tried this on angular material and it doesn't work. They don't have support for this attribute as expression. Maybe they decided support it only in the following way: `<mat-button-toggle-group multiple>`. 
This is the [code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/button-toggle/button-toggle.ts#L213) on github. Clearly is the an attr in the selector of the directive.

PD: The @Pterrat awnser is fine to do what you want.

Comment: Additionally, you can add an issue in angular-material github https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/new

Comment: @Pterrat no problem. Your answer is the correct for this question,  that's the important thing. I only wanted to explain why is not working. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar with mat-select (angular material 7) and at least for mat-select this works (where multiple is a boolean property on your class):

```
 <mat-select [(value)]="value"
              [multiple]="multiple">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options"
                [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```